# Remove BST and GMT from my data in R and just view the time

Tags: r, timestamp, binary-search-tree, gmt, anytime

I am trying to find the timestamp in R so I used the anytime function as follows:

```
Timestamp = anytime::anytime(paste(Date, Time))
```

but then I realise that the timestamp has BST and GMT. How can I get my timestamp without GMT or BST?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The function `anytime` returns a POSIX time object that you can display in any desired format. To omit the timezone, you would simply leave it out in the format specification:

```
x = anytime::anytime(paste(Date, Time))
Timestamp = format( x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" )
```

See `?format.POSIXct` for more information.

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I improved the answer and added some description of what's going on.